# Delete the connection and every file under the svn on the server

Tags: svn, command-line

Hi i have a repository at assembla and i'm using the svn to store there the new classes,changes etc.I have my servlet running on a server so i decide to connect assembla and the server to make automatic updates.I used the

```
     svn checkout http://blah...
     svn update
```

But there my problems start. I can't open my page. the web page could upload and even for  30 minutes without anything happening.Just uploading. So i decide to remove everything revolves around the svn. ANd i use the following command lines:

```
    find . -type d -name .svn
```

The result:

```
    ./.svn
```

And then i delete and this with the following:

```
   rm ./.svn -rf
```

Actually that i want to do is to delete everything related with the svn and the connection as the problems starts from there. Please provide me any command line or advise on how can i do this.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `svn export`. This will export the contents in your svn working copy to another directory except any svn related files/dirs.

If you just want to remove the .svn files, do enter the following command.

```
rm -r `find -type d -iname .svn`
```